# iPhone - Using AV framework to play two audio files one after another?

Tags: iphone, audio

I've few audio files in mp3 format.
One audio file plays "Hi", and another audio file plays "How are you". Similarly many other audio files.
I want to play two audio files one after another so that final audio speaks "Hi How are you".
I know how to play one audio file. But how can I queue them in such a way that user don't find any difference that they are two different files played one after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [AVQueuePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW20) or implement something similar manually (if targeting < 4.1)

Comment: Thanks badgerr, can you help me, can we put sleep or gap anything between two audio's. Like a person inhaling waiting for 2 secs and then exhaling .... :)